# Como tratar exceções ao excluir um registro com chave primaria referenciada em outra tabela no framework Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exceção

Estou com problemas na exclusão de um registro ao qual sua chave primaria foi referenciada em outro registro de outra tabela!

As tabelas são **disciplina** e **professor**, onde a chave primaria de **professor** está sendo referenciada na tabela **disciplina**!

Eu queria saber a forma correta de tratar essa exceção para retornar uma mensagem/aviso sem dar erro no sistema com a mensagem padrão do **laravel**!

Observação: Não quero usar o método `cascade`, apenas informar que não pode ser excluído porque o professor tem relação com uma disciplina!

```
public function delete(Request $dados)
{
    DB::table('professors')->where('cdprofessor', '=', $dados->cdprofessor)->delete();
    return redirect()->route('professor')->withStatus(__('Professor deletado com sucesso.'));
}
```

[image: Exceção do Laravel]

Comment: Como está seu action `delete()`

Comment: `public function delete(Request $dados){   
     DB::table('professors')->where('cdprofessor', '=', $dados->cdprofessor)->delete();
     return redirect()->route('professor')->withStatus(__('Professor deletado com sucesso.'));
}`

Answer (score 1):

O laravel tem uma forma de tratar exceções de forma globa, a classe `App/Exception/Handler.php`.

No seu caso, é possível que está sendo exibido uma Illuminate\Database\QueryException, ou seja, há um erro com sua query ou algo relacionado a execução dela, e esse é um erro defido a uma relação com a tabela.

Como a pergunta é como tratar o erro, o que importa é apenas o Exception Hand (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors), e para capturar esse erro, você precisa capturá-lo no método `render` ou `report` na classe `App/Exception/Handler.php`.

Para o método report, é esperado que seja gerado um log, não é nosso caso.

Iremos inserir a captura da exceção no método render:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\QueryException){

        preg_match('#\[(.*?)\]#',$exception->getPrevious()->getMessage(), $match);
        $mysql_error_code = $match[1];
        if($mysql_error_code == '23000'){
            return response()->json((["message" => 'Não é possível executar essa ação', "errors" => 'Chave estrangeira inválida'], 400);
        }
        return response()->json((["message" => 'Não é possível executar essa ação', "errors" => $exception->errors()], 400);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

O importante é saber que para tratar o erro, deve se verificar a ExceptionHandler do Framework no arquivo App/Exception/Handler.php.

Comment: Olá **AnthraxisBR**, obrigado pela explicação. Fiz da forma que você demostrou, o `return` que ficou dentro do `if()` não abriu na minha aplicação, mas consegui contornar com um `about();`. Porém ele pega todas as **exceções** do **query**. Então mais uma única dúvida: Como identificar se a **exceção** é de integridade da **foreign key**?

Comment: Olá @EriklesBonfimRibeiro, tenta ver se isso resolve: $exception->getPrevious()->getMessage(), o retorno dessa linha vai ser o mensagem de PDOException, ela retorna o texto do erro, use um regex pra recuperar o código do erro do Mysql, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-error-reference.html. Editei a resposta com uma alteração ali, mas não cheguei a testar aqui.